# jQuery Morphext Animation: Stop, Wait, Then Start Again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery Morphext Plugin to rotate some text. The plugin cycles through four text options and then stops. I'm now trying to get this animation to loop around again, say after 15 seconds, and just keep repeating that loop, but I can't get it to work.

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      function animateTitle() {
        jQuery("#js-rotating").Morphext({
          // The [in] animation type. Refer to Animate.css for a list of available animations.
          animation: "flipInX",
          // An array of phrases to rotate are created based on this separator. Change it if you wish to separate the phrases differently (e.g. So Simple | Very Doge | Much Wow | Such Cool).
          separator: ",",
          // The delay between the changing of each phrase in milliseconds.
          speed: 3000,
          complete: function() {
            // Called after the entrance animation is executed.
            if (this.index === 3) {
              this.stop(true);
            }
          }
        });
      };

      setTimeout(animateTitle, 5000);
    });
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wpdev.dotdynamic.ie/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wpdev.dotdynamic.ie/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<script src="http://wpdev.dotdynamic.ie/wp-includes/js/Morphext/dist/morphext.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://wpdev.dotdynamic.ie/wp-includes/js/Morphext/dist/morphext.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://wpdev.dotdynamic.ie/wp-includes/js/Morphext/dist/animate.css">
<span id="js-rotating">Text 1, Text 2, Text 3, Text 4</span> Rotates
```

This approach isn't working as all of my text to be rotated is displayed on the page until the first time interval is reached, and then after the Morphext function runs once the animation doesn't repeat.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please ensure that your code snippet is working.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow. I think I have figured that out now and the code snippet now runs.